# ClassNotFoundException on Maven Dependency Class org.apache.http.client

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, httpclient

I'm trying to build a simple API client, which uses `org.apache.http`for connecting to the API server. Locally everything works fine. I'm successfully connecting to the server and receive the data I want.

But, when I deploy my application to the server. I'm getting following exception:
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException from [Module "deployment.adobe-livecycle-jboss.ear:main" from Service Module Loader]`

I tried multiple different variants of versions of my depencies. Right now im using the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Both of the JARs appear in my Java Build Path, also the class which is "missing" is found in there.
Even when I build the project and search the JAR files libs folder, I can find the class...

I know there are some solutions to find online but none of them helped me.

Comment: Please don't use different versions for related dependencies. That is asking for trouble.

Comment: @JoãoDias I changed both dependencies to 4.4, Now I got the same error on a different class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpRequest from [Module "deployment.adobe-livecycle-jboss.ear:main" from Service Module Loader]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by a faulty maven local repository. Try looking for your maven local repository (It's generally a hidden folder like named`.m2\repository`), delete the folder `org\apache\httpcomponents` then clean compile your project.

---

**Edit:**
After further explanation of the problem, it seems that this is a deployment issue not a build one.

If it's the first time that you use this package in your build, then this package's jar must be defined somewhere in the deployment server, it seems that you are deploying in an Adobe environment which seems to be based on JBoss because of that line of log that you provided

```
[Module "deployment.adobe-livecycle-jboss.ear:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

Make sure to read the documentation of that environment on how to configure and define external modules.

Comment: Unfortunately the error persists

Comment: @oxicod You said you used JBoss for deployment, did you add the `<module name="org.apache.http" />` to your `module.xml` file? also make sure you create a module with the same name and put the jars in it

Comment: I actually don't have a module.xml file in my project as far as I know. I'm working on a adobe environment which is all set up and worked fine on previous deployments. Also I have a normal Maven Project and no Maven module

Comment: @oxicod If it's the first time that you use this package in your build, then your jar must be defined somewhere into that 3rd party environment, whatever it is, it seems to be using JBoss because of that line of log that you provided `[Module "deployment.adobe-livecycle-jboss.ear:main" from Service Module Loader]` and the `module` keyword indicates that you must define a new module somewhere somehow.

Comment: Ok thank you I will look into that